# iOS 5 Instance variables

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I'm slightly confused as to how ARC works, I know there is automatic reference counting but does this functionality work even for assigning raw instance variables (not using the properties).

For instance, if I have an instance variable `arr`:

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject {
   NSArray *arr;
}
```

Now if inside a method I assign this using an auto-released `NSArray`:

```
- (IBAction)test {
    arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"TEST"];
 }
```

What happens to this array? Does it just magically keep it until `arr` is reassigned to something else?

Now if I do something like:

```
self.arr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"TEST"];
```

What happens if it is strong vs. weak?

Comment: I would recommend reading Apple's Transitioning to ARC Release Notes document.

Comment: And for convenience: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, ARC works on raw ivar access. Just like local variables, ivars are implicitly `__strong` unless decorated with `__weak` or `__unsafe_unretained`. Therefore they will, by default, act like a property that's been marked `strong` (or `retain`, which under ARC is a synonym for `strong`).

Comment: Kevin, what happens with a `@synthesize`d property with `copy` semantics if you access the synthesized ivar directly. Does the compiler insert a `copy`?

Comment: @StevenKramer: No. Accessing ivars directly *always* ignores the memory management semantics of the property. The only time it matters is a synthesized ivar will pick up the weak/strong semantics of the property it's being synthesized from)

Comment: Thanks for the info Kevin. Just verified this in the debugger. A slightly odd, but understandable, choice I guess.